# Test Google Spreadsheets Add-On with custom functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function, google-apps-script-add-on

I have set up a Google Apps Scripts project with the intent of creating a Google Spreadsheets add-on with custom functions.  However, when I use the option "Test as add-on", I can't use the functions that I created.  When I paste the script code into the script editor opened from a spreadsheet it works fine, however.

Is this a limitation on how custom functions work in Spreadsheets, or am I simply doing something wrong?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle) offers only a cryptic remark: "Custom functions in Google Sheets use their own authorization mode, AuthMode.CUSTOM_FUNCTION, which is similar to LIMITED but has slightly different restrictions." No word about these _slight_ differences. What does your custom function attempt to do?

Comment: There are quite a few custom functions. They all pull data from a REST API using UrlFetchApp (or the CacheService). However, even a function that simply returns a constant string does not work. It is not that the function gives an error, but it is unknown in the sheet: it results in a #NAME.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: This answer was [cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34381535/1595451). I have made some updates there.

## Answer

According to Eric Koleda in [Code.gs - date_add_and_subtract](https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/blob/master/date_add_and_subtract/Code.gs) to make available the custom fuctions in an add-on it's required to include at least one add-on menu, but this is not working at this time.

## Remarks

There are a couple of related GAS issues, please star them:

- ["Test as add-on" from standalone project to Google Sheets doesn't link custom functions](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5603)
- [After activating an add-on, custom functions get stuck Loading... until spreadsheet refresh](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5590)